# PHP number format dots and commas

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting, price

Maybe it is something very easy but I am a bit lost here.

I got two different variables, one with a comma and one with a dot:

```
<?php
$price1 = "0,85";
$price2 = "0.85";

echo number_format((float)$price1, 2, ',', '');
// display as 0,85

echo number_format((float)$price2, 2, ',', '');
// display as 0,00
?>
```

I made this example to make it more clear but in live code it is like this:

```
<?php
echo number_format((float)$prijs, 2, ',', '');
?>
```

And price could be stored in database as "0.85" or "0,85".

How can I echo it that no matter it is with a dot or a comma it always shows the price with a comma and 2 decimals?

Comment: Why do you store both ways? That's asking for trouble. What if someone enters `3,500.50` or `3.500,50` both are valid in different parts of the world. And that's just two examples.

Comment: If you want to do anything mathematical (add/subtract) you have to use sensible number format i.e. `0.85` if your LOCALE (clue) uses something else then convert the numbers only in the Presentation layer

Comment: @Andreas it is a field users can fill out themselves... I cant block dots because they also can fill in 1.354,45

Comment: Then you restrict what they fill in.

Comment: Storing both ways is madness. Is `1,100` "one thousand one hundred" or "one and one tenth"? You should use only a single format for storage.

Comment: Then you have to convert the number for storing on the database. I also assume you are storing the numbers in a VARCHAR or similiar, which makes simple queries like `SUM(prijs)` so much more complex

Comment: Ok, I get this is not the way. Thanks for the answers, will edit the field that they are limited in some ways. Thanks